# SwiftUI dragging an object lags on newer iPhones

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have this really simple code for dragging an object on the screen:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@GestureState var translation = CGSize.zero
var body: some View {
    Rectangle()
        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
        .offset(translation)
        .gesture(
            DragGesture().updating($translation, body: { value, state, transaction in
                state = value.translation
            })
       )
}}
```

When testing on device, it works perfectly smooth on an older model (iPhone 7 Plus), but it's kind of laggy on newer ones (iPhone 13 mini and iPhone 13). On simulators I could not reproduce it, only on a real device. Is there something I'm missing?

[iphone13Mini](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13OX81h_uFYEEDVisJAB2VzppzltwdLdD/view?usp=sharing)

[iphone 7Plus](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jkvDfkF9F4ZlKcakm2zpYrg9CQ65zI4C/view?usp=sharing)

The difference is only slightly seen on the videos, but in real life the lag feels more somehow on the 13.

Comment: I’m seeing similar issues with my iPhone 13 mini and iOS 15.6. Have you run the tests with a beta of iOS 16 already? Is it any better?

Comment: No I haven’t, but it’s a good idea to try. I raised it in the Feedback Assistant but no answer of course

Comment: After upgrading my iPhone 13 mini to the fresh release of iOS 16, I gave it a try again and unfortunately, the issue is still present. Have you filed a feedback?

Comment: Yes I have: https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/10806309
No answers yet. I also used one of my Code-Level Supports on this, they told me that until they don't answer the feedback assistant ticket, they can't move forward, so still waiting.

Comment: That’s unfortunate. I’d appreciate if you keep this thread updated when you hear back from Apple.

Comment: If anyone is looking for a temporary fix until Apple delivers an official solution, wrapping the offset update in a `withAnimation(.linear)` makes the transition smooth, although it does introduce a very slight delay. I still find it better than the alternative though.

Comment: I think `withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.01))` would reduce the delay. @JonasZell

Comment: @Tamás Horváth yep, that's what I ended up going with